# Can a Vaadin radio button group be styled like a group of buttons instead?

Tags: css, vaadin

Is it possible to style radio-buttons in vaadin like a group of buttons, and checked one will be colored?
[image]

Im expecting to use group of button like radiobutton. One can be checked, others unchecked.

Comment: I can't guarantee that it's not possible to style radio-buttons like this, but I'd just create a component with some buttons in a HorizontalLayout and click-listener that toggles the color and does whatever else is supposed to happen when a button is clicked (for instance keeping track of the active button in some state-holding variable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming Vaadin 23 (the structure of the components may change in other versions), it seems feasible.

[image]

In global styles.css, add:

```
vaadin-radio-group.buttons vaadin-radio-button {
    border: 1pt solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    --radio-button-wrapper-display: none;
}

vaadin-radio-group.buttons vaadin-radio-button[checked] {
    background: orange;
}
```

In the theme components/vaadin-radio-button.css, add

```
.vaadin-radio-button-wrapper { display: var(--radio-button-wrapper-display,block); }
```

(that will hide the radio circle, but you can still select it by clicking the label, which remains visible)

[image: the vaadin-radio-button-wrapper]

And set the RadioButtonGroup class to `buttons`.

Comment: Thank you, Javier. Just one point to clarify
What do you mean 'And set the RadioButtonGroup class to buttons.' ?

Comment: @AshamazShomakhov `yourRBG.addClassName("buttons")`